# Symfony2 - The type name specified for the service does not match

Tags: php, forms, symfony, service

i try to configure EasyAdminBundle with my own ImageType to upload file in my ArticleType.
So i created this service in `app\config\services.yml` :

```
services:
    oah_news_form_type_image: 
        class: OAH\NewsBundle\Form\ImageType
        tags: [ { name: form.type, alias: 'oah_news_form_type_image' } ]
```

and tried to call it in my `app\config\config.yml` :

```
easy_admin:
entities:
        Article:
            class: OAH\NewsBundle\Entity\Article
            form:
                fields:
                    - Titre
                    - Auteur
                    - Date
                    - Categorie
                    - { property : 'Image', type : oah_news_form_type_image}
```

but i've the following error and i don't know how to fix it :

```
The type name specified for the service "oah_news_form_type_image" does not match the actual name. Expected "oah_news_form_type_image", given "oah_newsbundle_image"
```

my ImageType :

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'OAH\NewsBundle\Entity\Image'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'oah_newsbundle_image';
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Which version of symfony do you use? Do you have getName() method inside the FormType?

Comment: I have the 2.6.12 version of symfony. I edited my first post to add my ImageType

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears your alias name must match your `return` from `getName()`.

Answer (score 2):

@Flushdrew Have you managed to fix your issue after my comment? Anyway I'll give complete answer here. I asked about symfony version you use, because `getName` method was removed in 3.0 and the FormType can be identified by its static class name.

In the 2.7 and below in the `FormType` class you have to provide a `getName` "announce" method, that will inform other FormTypes that this particular form uses this particular name.

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'oah_news_form_type_image';
}
```

Actually `alias: 'oah_news_form_type_image'` in the `services.yml` has to match the one in the `getName()`

You can read more about it here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: Yes sorry for the time but it works perfectly. Thank you